# Serial bi-directional (one-wire half-duplex) digispark device works however answers itselfs

Tags: arduino, serial, c++, 1-wire, attiny85

I followed this guide to create an one wire bi-directional (debug) device for a Digispark (Attiny85):

https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/debugging (see section Bi-directional Serial Debugging with a single I/O) or see schematic in sourcecode below:

```
/*
  https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/debugging

                        SERIAL SINGLE I/O
                         DEBUGGING CABLE
            ___________________/\__________________
           /                                       \
                                              ____
 .--------.                                  |    \
 |    GND |--------------------------------+---o5  \
 |        |                           47K  | |   9o |
 |        |                        .--###--' | o4   |
 |  DEBUG |                  4.7K  |         |   8o |
 |  TX_RX |-------------------###--+--|<|------o3   |    ---> To regular RS232 SubD 9 pins Male of PC
 |   PIN  |        ^               | 1N4148  |   7o |         or to RS232/USB adapter
 |        |        |               '-----------o2   |         Connector PIN 2: RX (receive) 
 '--------'        |                         |   6o |         Connector PIN 3: TX (transmit)
  ATtiny85       Single                      | o1  /
 (Digispark)      I/O                        |____/
                                          SubD 9 pins
                                            Female


 Note:

    Trick to be less intrusive: use a �high� data rate (38400 is fine)
      -> less time wasted in ISR and for transmitting each character.
    You can still upload your sketch modifications through the USB interface
    whilst the additionnal serial port is selected as Serial port in the IDE.

*/


#include <TinyPinChange.h>
#include "SoftSerial.h"

#define DEBUG_TX_RX_PIN         3 //Adjust here your Tx/Rx debug pin

SoftSerial MyDbgSerial(DEBUG_TX_RX_PIN, DEBUG_TX_RX_PIN, true); //true allows to connect to a regular RS232 without RS232 line driver

void setup()
{
  MyDbgSerial.begin(9600); //After MyDbgSerial.begin(), the serial port is in rxMode by default
  MyDbgSerial.txMode(); //Before sending a message, switch to txMode
  MyDbgSerial.println(F("\nDebug enabled"));
  MyDbgSerial.rxMode(); //switch to rxMode to be ready to receive some commands
}

void loop()
{
  if(MyDbgSerial.available())
  {
    MyDbgSerial.txMode();
    MyDbgSerial.print(F("\nReceived: "));MyDbgSerial.write(MyDbgSerial.read());MyDbgSerial.print(F("\n"));
    MyDbgSerial.rxMode();
  }
}
```

---

**The 'device' I created looks like this:**
[image: The device #1 - top]
[image: The device #2 - bottom]
[image: The device #3 - With usb serial COM port]

---

**Doublechecking this pinout to be sure (female -> male):**
[image: female-to-male]

---

The 'device' works but answers itselfs, there is something wrong (schematic?). For example: When you enter "hello" in the serial monitor, it replies directly with the same "hello" also without a Digispark attached/connected. When Digispark attached/connected, the Digispark seems to receive nothing.

---

So what could be wrong, is the schematic correct?

Comment: go with a 3 or 4 wire system

Comment: If the serial monitor displays what you type, even with no external device connected, the serial monitor program may have "Local Echo" enabled.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a debugging question which has been abandoned for *years* without necessary follow up effort to identify the problem.  No resolution is possible without such action by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Based on that schematic, that's exactly how it will react on your pc console program with or without something attached at the other end. You tied the tx to the rx, essentially a loop back device. Ignore the "echo".

As for your digispark not responding, have you set your console at the right speed and parity and stop settings?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Take a look at my code, everything is set to default, just for testing. The USB serial adapter using defaults too. If I send just "hello", the serial monitor shows nothing. If I enter "hello"in the serial monitor, it replies with "hello".

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider this instead.  ...........

[image]

The Tx/Rx on left is looped back.
The Tx Rx on the right is isolated for no loopback.

Use twisted pair between the two ports as common mode  noise can be an issue to tie the grounds.

Comment: You may want to consider explaining why he may want to consider this.

Comment: thx Nick, solution added.